# Disappointment when trying to lock file for reading

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to make each thread read its own text file.

```
   private void burden() {

    File mainFolder = new File("C:\\FilesToRead");
    File[] files = mainFolder.listFiles();
    String freeFile;

    for (File file : files) {

        FileChannel channel;
        FileLock lock = null;
        try {
            channel = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r").getChannel();;
            lock = channel.lock();
            // Ok. We get the lock
            readFile(file.getName());

        } catch (OverlappingFileLockException e) {
            continue; // File is open by someone else                 
        } catch (FileNotFoundException f) {

        } catch (IOException ex) {

        } catch (NonWritableChannelException n) {
            System.out.println("NonWritableChannelException");
        } finally {
            try {
                lock.release();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("IOException!");
            }
        }

    }
} // burden();
```

I get this picture in the debugger:

[image]

The next step will bring me to the NonWritableChannelException.

I can't understand why as I tried to lock file for reading.

Comment: You should show the exception.

Comment: Don't swallow exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you also need to lock the writable channel here so make your code,

```
channel = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw").getChannel();
```

This should work.

Comment: Some outputstreams may modify this file.So need to eliminate that case also.

Comment: Locks are advisory anyway; even if you have a lock, nothing will prevent another program, or even thread of your current JVM, to open the file for writing.

Answer (score 3):

The javadoc gives the answer. You use `.lock()`, which is equivalent to calling `.lock(0L, Long.MAX_VALUE, false)`.

And the third parameter, a boolean, is described as (emphasis mine):

> true to request a shared lock, in which case this channel must be open for reading (and possibly writing); **false** to request an exclusive lock, in which case **this channel must be open for writing** (and possibly reading)

You have to `.lock(0L, Long.MAX_VALUE, true)`

---

Also, if you are using Java 7, use `FileChannel.open()`